# Phonegap installation issue (shasum check failed)

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm trying to install phonegap on Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail). It runs fine for a whole lot of packages and then all of a sudden stops... Here is the output of the last couple of lines...

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.1.22.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.1.22.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-2.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-2.0.1.tgz
npm ERR! Error: shasum check failed for /home/thomas/tmp/npm-28537-
    2GGcJK29/1380571519720-0.5711500460747629/tmp.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 4bf7f005fe1038c4fe9207603b961c97bd0ba5a3
npm ERR! Actual:   b237f063a8d2d81a648e08b7173f9b1e040cc77f
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sha/index.js:38:8
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.<anonymous> 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sha/index.js:85:7)
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:125:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:896:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:316:11)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-31-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd /home/thomas/node
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.8-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/thomas/node/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What is this checksum it's looking for? Why is it supposed to be what it says and why would it be different? Google hasn't been able to provide me with a solid answer here.

I have no idea what I can do to fix this - any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @animuson don't see how this is a duplicate of a question asked 21 hours ago when this one was asked almost 3 months ago (shouldn't that be a duplicate of this?), but thanks for pointing me to the answer in any case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strangely the solution to this issue doesn't appear on any search engine. Anyway, according to [this issue](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/4329) on NPM issue on Github, all you need to do is to install  npm-1.3.19.tgz as shown below, first:

```
npm install https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.19.tgz
```

Then installing PhoneGap/Cordova the usual way. I've tried it and it's working for me.

**UPDATE:**

Install whatever package that failed, as shown below:

```
npm install [the URL right before the shasum check fails]
```

Then installing PhoneGap/Cordova the usual way. I've tried it and it's working for me.

Comment: As https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.19.tgz no longer exists so please use https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.21.tgz

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. (on Mac OSX v10.8.5)

As a result of having executed four or five times of same commands repeatedly, I succeeded in installation.

Comment: Worked for me too on windows