# shasum check failed for installing cordova using npm

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm working on win-7 64 bit. I've downloaded & installed NodeJs 1.3.14

and then I tried to install `cordova` using the [guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface)

and ran the command `npm install -g cordova` and it ended up with errors and below are the last  lines of the log :

```
8106 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'node_modules/which/bin/which', 438, 420 ]
8107 silly lockFile b0283f67-ing-npm-cache-npm-1-3-14-package tar://C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\npm\1.3.14\package
8108 silly lockFile b0283f67-ing-npm-cache-npm-1-3-14-package tar://C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\npm\1.3.14\package
8109 silly lockFile 20b15fea-npm-cache-npm-1-3-14-package-tgz tar://C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\npm\1.3.14\package.tgz
8110 silly lockFile 20b15fea-npm-cache-npm-1-3-14-package-tgz tar://C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\npm\1.3.14\package.tgz
8111 verbose chmod C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\npm\1.3.14\package.tgz 644
8112 silly chown skipping for windows C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\npm\1.3.14\package.tgz
8113 silly lockFile 150d9711-try-npmjs-org-npm-npm-1-3-14-tgz https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.14.tgz
8114 silly lockFile 150d9711-try-npmjs-org-npm-npm-1-3-14-tgz https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.14.tgz
8115 silly lockFile c1177926-npm-1-3-14 npm@1.3.14
8116 silly lockFile c1177926-npm-1-3-14 npm@1.3.14
8117 silly lockFile 8b2e1d24-npm-1-3-x npm@1.3.x
8118 silly lockFile 8b2e1d24-npm-1-3-x npm@1.3.x
8119 silly lockFile c8e2010f-lator-ripple-emulator-0-9-18-tgz https://registry.npmjs.org/ripple-emulator/-/ripple-emulator-0.9.18.tgz
8120 silly lockFile c8e2010f-lator-ripple-emulator-0-9-18-tgz https://registry.npmjs.org/ripple-emulator/-/ripple-emulator-0.9.18.tgz
8121 silly lockFile e7de7f23-ripple-emulator-0-9-18 ripple-emulator@0.9.18
8122 silly lockFile e7de7f23-ripple-emulator-0-9-18 ripple-emulator@0.9.18
8123 verbose about to build C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
8124 info C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova unbuild
8125 info preuninstall cordova@3.1.0-0.2.0
8126 info uninstall cordova@3.1.0-0.2.0
8127 verbose true,C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules,C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules unbuild cordova@3.1.0-0.2.0
8128 verbose C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm,[object Object] binRoot
8129 info postuninstall cordova@3.1.0-0.2.0
8130 error Error: shasum check failed for C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-13152-JkoqFrUn\1384785262909-0.39034782187081873\tmp.tgz
8130 error Expected: 022df983c7dd613aee3c761126d92608b9d59efd
8130 error Actual:   42439770db057c2fffc6f2c563aea9674c083430
8130 error     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha\index.js:38:8
8130 error     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha\index.js:85:7)
8130 error     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
8130 error     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
8130 error     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
8131 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
8131 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
8131 error or email it to:
8131 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
8132 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
8133 error command "C:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
8134 error cwd C:\Users\hp
8135 error node -v v0.10.22
8136 error npm -v 1.3.14
8137 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm new to NodeJS & Cordova, please also let me know if I can find answer at some other place.

Comment: There is an answer on this question that says it worked after trying it a few times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103016/phonegap-installation-issue-shasum-check-failed  Are you on a slow connection? Maybe you're not able to download the full cordova file which is why it is failing the checksum...

Comment: I'm on a 1Mbps connection and I've already seen that question, but I'm trying since past 7+ times and it's still the same.

Comment: It worked this time. For all others who face the same problem, just keep trying & it'll work.

Comment: I've filed the issue and they accepted and resolved it - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5640

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for filing the issue!

Answer (score 0):

That sam issue i had, i ran the comman below, then again tried to install module worked for me.

npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/