# $ npm install https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.19.tgz is not fond error

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

whenever I am running this command like:

```
$ npm install https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.19.tgz:
```

I am getting error during phonegap install time.

Thanks
Tarun

Comment: Looking at the registry result, the latest version of npm seems to be the 1.3.18

Comment: try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20636160/1977815

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this problem as well. I used the following solution:

- Use curl to grab text from http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/latest
- Searched text for `http.*tgz`
- Replace the tgz reference that is returning an error with the one found in the text, then rerun npm install